# Numpy - Create an array of views

Tags: arrays, numpy, view

I have many 5000x3 numpy data arrays. Sometimes I need to 'stack' some of them, i.e. if I want to stack 3 it becomes a 3*5000x3 array. Using usual `numpy.vstack(...)` is not feasible, as it creates a new array (copy), which is not only slow but also takes unnecessary memory. I want to instead create a new 'array' of vertically stacked views, e.g. an array `x` consisting only of views where `x[0:5000,:]` is *pointing* to one 5000x3 array and `x[5000:10000,:]` to another. This new array `x` is only a combined view on the actual data arrays, so I can do operations on the view which manipulates both data arrays at once, without ever creating copies (unless of course I use fancy indexing etc.). Is this somehow possible?

Comment: No.  a `view` is an alternative way of accessing ONE contiguous data buffer.  You are dealing with several different buffers (each with 15000 elements).  Each of those buffers is located at a different point memory.  A list or object array can 'point' to each of those arrays, but they can't be addressed as one contiguous array.

Comment: Yes it is possible. See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html#numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided